# Error on application tried to present a Split View Controllers modally

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm using storyboards and I want to load a specific set of XIBs, the problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a Split View Controllers modally <PlaceHolderViewController: 0x38e890>
```

In the `PlaceHolderViewController` I have a button that loads the xib with this code, I have no problem loading the xib from the iPhone but on the iPad I'm having this problem.

This is the code:

```
- (IBAction)actionButtonConversor:(id)sender {
    ConverterViewController *converterViewController;
    UnitSelectViewController *unitSelectViewController;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        converterViewController = [[ConverterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConverterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        unitSelectViewController= [[UnitSelectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UnitSelectViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:converterViewController];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.48235297203063965f blue:0.63137257099151611f alpha:1];
        [self presentModalViewController:self.navigationController animated:YES];
    } else {
        converterViewController = [[ConverterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConverterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        unitSelectViewController= [[UnitSelectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UnitSelectViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:unitSelectViewController];
        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:converterViewController];
        masterNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.48235297203063965f blue:0.63137257099151611f alpha:1];
        detailNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.48235297203063965f blue:0.63137257099151611f alpha:1];

        self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

        self.splitViewController.delegate = converterViewController;

        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:self.splitViewController animated:YES]; // ERROR comes from here i think
    }

    unitSelectViewController.delegate = converterViewController;
    converterViewController.unitSelectViewController = unitSelectViewController;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem looks obvious.  The following is copied from the `UISplitViewController` documentation:

> "you must always install the view from a UISplitViewController object
>   as the root view of your application’s window. [...] Split view
>   controllers cannot be presented modally."

In other words, what you're seeing is intended behavior.

Comment: Can you confirm how they should they be presented ?

Comment: @drlobo -- Assuming code inside the application delegate, something like: `self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;`